# Why "this" in this case?

Tags: adjectives

Ivan: Could you give me that book on the table over there?
Sergio: Do you mean this book here?

Ivan: Yes, that book.
Sergio: Here you are. Oh, could you give me that magazine too on the table over there?

Ivan: This one? Sure, here you are.
Ivan: Hey Sergio, do you know who *this* actress is on the magazine cover?

https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/this-or-that/

Why is it not "that actress"?

The magazine is not close to Ivan since he has just given it to Sergio.

In addition the magazine has already been mentioned and we clearly know about which cover is Ivan speaking.

Comment: Where did you see the text?

Comment: This link should work now

Comment: this and that can be quite difficult for French speakers.

Comment: The next sentence is: "Sergio: No, I do not know who that actress is." Thus, the magazine seems closer to Ivan than to Sergio. I suspect that they are talking about a different magazine or there is a mistake in the dialogue. The fact that Ivan has two consecutive lines here (and nowhere else), as well as the fact that I found several blatant errors on that website within one minute, suggests to me that it is probably a mistake.

Comment: He picks up the magazine and points to the woman and says this because it is in his hand...

Answer (score 4):

I'd understand the dialogue to mean that Ivan asks the question about the actress as he is passing the magazine to Sergio.  As he asks the question, the magazine is still in his hands and so "this" is used.

If he had completely passed the magazine to Sergio, he would use "that". Of course we don't have any pictures, so we can only speculate.

I note that Ivan already knows the answer to this question (see dialogue at the linked site). He is asking it to test Sergio, not to find out the actress's name. And he has previously met and been photographed with her. So mentally he is "close".  That may influence his choice.